# combobox selected index between two values

Tags: vb.net

how can I make select case for index between two values
like

```
Select Case True
        Case ComboBox1.SelectedIndex >= 0 and <= 3
            messagebox.show("Done")
   End Select
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer is in the MSDN documentation about [SELECT ... CASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx)

```
Dim index = ComboBox1.SelectedIndex 
Select Case index
    Case 0 To 3
        MessageBox.Show("Done")
    Case Else
        MessageBox.Show("What? Else??")
End Select
```

**EDIT**
An interesting situation is the following that has let me without a clear explanation, so if someone could add to this answer is well accepted: Suppose to have this code.... (and OPTION STRICT OFF)

```
Sub Main
    Dim cbo = new ComboBOx()
    cbo.Items.Add("Steve")
    cbo.Items.Add("John")
    cbo.Items.Add("Mark")
    cbo.Items.Add("Andrew")
    cbo.Items.Add("Luke")
    cbo.Items.Add("Robert")
    cbo.Items.Add("Max")
    cbo.Items.Add("Carl")
    cbo.Items.Add("Paul")  ' added 9 items
    cbo.SelectedIndex = 0  ' set Steve as selected
    Select cbo.SelectedIndex
        case cbo.SelectedIndex = 2 to 3
            Console.WriteLine("DONE 2-3")
        case cbo.SelectedIndex = 0 to 1
            Console.WriteLine("DONE 0-1")
        case else
            Console.WriteLine("ELSE")
        End Select
End Sub
```

I would expect the `DONE 0-1` message but instead this code returns `DONE 2-3`, as well for every other SelectedIndex less than 4. It returns ELSE only when setting the SelectedIndex to 4.
I have not found a way to return DONE 0-1 unless moving the case block 0-1 before the 2-3 one.

Comment: can't it be
Case ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0 To 2

Comment: Well, at first glance I would have said no, then I have tried and surprisingly the compiler accepted the code. But looking in depth it produces wrong results if the index is less that the first term of the expression (SelectedIndex=1 enters the case 2-3)

Comment: Ah, well, the last example compiles only if you have OPTION STRICT OFF